# Why does Vue.js allow pushing to prop array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js displays warning when we try to change the prop value directly, like this:

```
Vue.component('Games', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li v-for="game in games">{{ game }}</li>
            </ol>
            <button @click="clear">Clear games</button>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['games'],
    methods: {
        clear: function () {
            this.games = [];
        }
    }
});
```

The warning being displayed is:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.

I know why that happens, but what I find surprising is that it doesn't happen with `.push()`. If I change the method to add a value to the array instead of rewriting it, there's no warning:

```
methods: {
    add: function () {
        this.games.push('Whatever');
    }
}
```

Why is there no warning? How is pushing directly to the prop fine and rewriting is not?

Comment: The prop being pushed to is an array. After pushing a new value, it is still an array. I believe vue doesn't do a deep watch on props out of the box (i.e, it doesn't care about what's _inside_ the array).

Comment: How does it matter that it's of the same type? Vue.js even has its own wrapper for `Array.push` from what I know, so it would make things even easier to control. Changing the props is said to be wrong in case of re-rendering. It's not about the type, but about the value being different than a value being passed in a prop.

Comment: I'll post a more in depth answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just because `Array` is kind of reference memory. When you have `Array` or `Object` stored in any variable it's a reference variable.

`Memory management` in such case,  The reference variable will points to a memory address in `heap` so you can add more n more value to address. However you cannot just replace that address with any new value even with the new address.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought of myself shortly after asking the question (hence my comment under Lewis's answer. Would you still consider it an anti-pattern to push to props directly?

Comment: I think your updated part actually messes the answer up. It's enough to say it's a reference and that what Vue warns about is changing the value, meaning the value as a variable low-level content. At first I thought Vue wants to warn about an anti-pattern, but it looks like this warning is purely technical. Can you please delete the edited part? It adds nothing and makes it more confusing. This problem has nothing to do with deep cloning.

Comment: ah -  Valid, it will confuse - It's just the point I want to put to avoid such case - You are right ! Removed Thanks

Comment: How to clone an object is a topic for another story.

Answer (score 2):

### As the warning says, one results in unexpected behaviour

When a component is updated/rendered, the props are written as values to the underlying component model. This can happen again at "any" time. This will often happen with components rendered in v-if or v-for conditions. In this case the prop value is written again from the parent to the child.

If the child increases the counter it will only increase it's local copy of the prop, the original value `parent.data.counter` will still remain at the value 5. If the parent is updated (for example by setting `counter=counter-1`) then Vue will override the value in the child with the new value from the parent. So all changes of the child are lost - and this can lead to unexpected behaviour.

### This problem will not happen, if the prop is a reference, which is mutated

If the prop is an array, there exists only a single copy of this array in memory. Any mutation of the array will change the original array in parent as well as in child. This will only work for mutations of the array itself, if you would e.g. try `child.propArray = child.propArray.slice(3)` you will have the same problems as before. Since slice does not change the original array, but creates a copy the child will have a different reference than the parent and unexpected behaviour will likely manifest.

## Here is a code-fiddle demonstrating the issues:

```js
Vue.component('child-comp', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['counter', 'arr'],
  template: `<h3>Child Counter: {{ counter }} <button @click="inc">+</button>
     -- Array: {{arr}} <button @click="push">push</button></h3></h3>`,
  methods: { inc() { this.counter++ }, push() { this.arr.push(this.arr.length+1) } }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: { counter: 1, arr: [] },
  methods: { inc() { this.counter++ }, push() { this.arr.push(this.arr.length+1) } }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="main">
   <h3>Main Counter: {{counter}} <button @click="inc">+</button>
     -- Array: {{arr}} <button @click="push">push</button></h3>
   <child-comp :counter="counter" :arr="arr"></child-comp>
   <child-comp :counter="counter" :arr="arr"></child-comp>
</main>
```

Comment: So if you really want to change a prop in a child, you can wrap it in an object and pass the object as prop. - The basic philosophy of Vue is for the child to emit a message to the parent and to change the original value instead of mutating props. This will work great for simple tasks, but if you pass down complex objects through a series of nested components, bubbling these events all the way up will make your code very hard to read and debug. - Alternatives are VueX or a good ownership model for data in your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The prop being pushed to is an array. After pushing a new value, it is still an array. I believe vue doesn't do a deep watch on props out of the box (i.e, it doesn't care about what's inside the array).

To quote [this](https://michaelnthiessen.com/how-to-watch-nested-data-vue/) article;

> ```
> const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> // array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> Now you update the array by pushing some more values into it:
>
> array.push(5);
> array.push(6);
> array.push(7);
> // array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> ```
>
> Here's the question: has array changed?
>
> Well, it's not that simple.
>
> The contents of array have changed, but the variable array still
>   points to the same Array object. The array container hasn't changed,
>   but what is inside of the array has changed.
>
> So when you watch an array or an object, Vue has no idea that you've
>   changed what's inside that prop. You have to tell Vue that you want it
>   to inspect inside of the prop when watching for changes.

Article By Michael Thiessen,
Posted Oct 2018 - All credit to them.

In response to your comment about this still being an anti-pattern, I'd say this;

If we think about why mutating props on a component directly is an anti-pattern in the first place, the reasoning still stands. To quote Michael again (I keep stumbling across his stuff by accident, I promise);

> "We do this because it ensures that each component is isolated from
>   each other. From this we can guarantee a few things that help us in
>   thinking about our components: Only the component can change it's own
>   state. Only the parent of the component can change the props."

Comment: I think I understand it now, but if I'm correct, your answer is only partially true. I think it's about the value of the prop itself, which in case of objects is just a reference. So if we mutate the array, the reference doesn't change - it's still the same point in memory. I wonder if that's still an anti-pattern to mutate props directly though, even if they are objects.

Comment: Moved this comment in to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense totally - I believe the main purpose of the components is to be autonomic. With `Array.push` on the prop they no longer are. I always feel a little disappointed when these things happen in JavaScript - you need to be careful with that loose language.