# Can't pass checked value to parent component from custom checkbox component

Tags: vue.js, emit

In my custom checkbox component, I'm trying to pass the value of the checkbox form field to my parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="custom-checkbox">
    <div :class="{ 'bg-white': value }">
      <input
        :id="checkboxId"
        type="checkbox"
        :checked="value"
        v-model="value"
        @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)"
      />
    </div>

    <label :for="checkboxId">
      <slot />
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    checkboxId: {
      type: String,
      default: "checkbox-1"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
>   mutated: "value"

I tried to add:

```
data() {
  return {
    checkedValue: this.value
  };
}
```

... then replace `v-model="value"` with `v-model="checkedValue"` but the checkbox doesn't check anymore and I still don't get the value of it in parent component.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need to set the checked value or listen to the change event if you're using v-model. What does the parent component look like?

Comment: Also never mutate a reference path, that's why you are getting warning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56596784/why-does-vue-js-allow-pushing-to-prop-array/56597083#56597083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are still directly mutating `value`, it does not matter if you catch the `@change` event or not.

Try creating a computed component with a getter/setter in your child component.

```
computed: {
    checked: {
        get() {
            return this.value;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$emit("input", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Use `checked` as your checkbox `v-model`. No need to bind anything to `:checked`, only `v-model` will suffice.

You can pass the value using `v-model` to this component in the parent.

For reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: How are you using this component in the parent? Please update your post.

Answer (score 0):

For the record.

**CustomCheckbox.vue**

```
<template>
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="value" @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["value"]
};
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
       <custom-checkbox v-model="checked"></custom-checkbox>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomCheckbox from "./components/CustomCheckbox";

export default {
    data: {
        checked: true
    },
    components: {
        CustomCheckbox
    }
};
</script>
```